# It's "scenes comparisons" or "scene comparisons"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, attributive-nouns

I make videos comparing scenes from 2 movies. I use scenes (it's always more than one movie) or scene in the title?

Comment: Scenes comparisons

Comment: A noun that is used attributively doesn't take a plural form.

Comment: If you use the plural, you have to say, "Scenes' Comparison." But note that as native speakers, we would say, "Scene Comparison" for the reason user178049 mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use "scene comparisons" in the title. It is partially due to the fact that generally though we compare a multitude of things, at a time we're looking at *one specific scene* in, say, movie A with a similar/contrasting scene in movie B.

It has a resemblance with "profit comparisons". Although the profits *are* of more than one type (net profit, gross profit, operating profit, etc.), the singular form "profit" is more commonly used.